# Finding a cell in an Excel file with VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I never asked a question here but I'm desperate and I can't find the solution to my problem.

I am programming with VBA for Access. I must get the value of a specific cell in a specific Excel file. To get this value I must Find the cell first, and thus comes my problem.

When I try to use the .Find method to get the column of the cell I need, it gives me error "13", type incompatibility.

This is what I'm doing:

```
Dim col As Integer
Dim appExcel As Excel.Application
Dim wbExcel As Excel.Workbook
Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
appExcel.Visible = True
Set wbExcel = Workbooks.Open("J:\EXPLOITATION\INDEXATION des tarifs\2017\Indexation GO client 2017.xls")
appExcel.Sheets("Indices GO 2017").Select
col = appExcel.Range("A22:Z22").Find("mai-2017", xlWhole, False, False).Column
```

Basically like this I get the column of the cell (because the cell I want is in the same column as the cell I found), then I will do the same to find the row, then I can get the value of the cell with the row and column.

On a side note, how can I open an excel file that starts with the name "Indexation" followed by anything else? (what in sql would be *)

Thank you so much, I need this to finish my thesis.
Cordially,
Voodoo.

Comment: http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/

Comment: `On a side note, how can I open an excel file that starts with the name "Indexation" followed by anything else? (what in sql would be *)` Loop through the directory using `*` wildcard and then open the file

Comment: Mind the types: `"mai-2017"` is a string, while in Excel dates are represented as numbers. Use the `DATEVALUE` function to convert strings to excel numbers.

Comment: > Loop through the directory using * wildcard and then open the file
How do I loop through files in a directory? A recordset?

>Mind the types: "mai-2017" is a string, while in Excel dates are represented as numbers. Use the DATEVALUE function to convert strings to excel numbers.
I tried DATEVALUE and also CDate but it still gives me the type incompatibility problem.

Comment: Instead of `appExcel.Sheets("Indices GO 2017").Select
col = appExcel.Range("A22:Z22").Find("mai-2017", xlWhole, False, False).Column` you should use  `col = appExcel.Sheets("Indices GO 2017").Range("A22:Z22").Find("mai-2017", xlWhole, False, False).Column`

Comment: I tried using that but it still gives me type incompatibility...

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> .Find("mai-2017", xlWhole, False, False)
> ```

Remove the useless parameters, first off they are misplaced. for example the second parameter should be a `Range` (cell) where to start the search. `xlWhole` is a number, not a range. Its position is the 4th in the parameter list, not the second.

The parameters are also of the wrong type. `False` for what, which parameters.
anyway, it doesn't seem that you need anything else, just the first parameter, so let's make life easier:

```
.Find("mai-2017")
```

If you really need to match whole cell at most, this:

```
.Find("mai-2017",, xlWhole)
```

Finally, as per @ErikvonAsmuth in the comments section, a match wont be found if the searched cell is formatted as date, because its inner value is actually a number. In that case, try to match the date type, like this:

```
.Find(DateValue("May-2017"))
```

---

Since your row has dates, try this to match the first occurrence of a date within may 2017 in the row:

```
col = appExcel.Evaluate("AGGREGATE(15, 6, COLUMN('Indices GO 2017'!22:22)" & _
"/ (MONTH('Indices GO 2017'!22:22)=5)/(YEAR('Indices GO 2017'!22:22)=2017), 1)")
```

You can easily adapt it to return the first date within any given month (`5` corresponds to May) in row 22.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but now it gives me "Object variable or With block variable not set (Error 91)"

Comment: @Voodoo it means not found. Which version did you try exactly and how?

Comment: Now I tried creating a variable that will store the range, and then get the column from that range but now it crashes on the last line.
`Dim c As Range
Set c = appExcel.Sheets("Indices GO 2017").Range("A22:Z22").Find(DateValue(DateDebut))
    col = c.Column`

Comment: I can help more if you show me how are the data in your range. Are they actual dates or strings?

Comment: I had to check the properties of the date cells to check it (I didn't create this Excel file, I only need data from it). The type of cell is "personalized" with "mmm-aa" (which might be month, year as its in french)

Comment: Well, that sounds like a date to me. Note that `Find(DateValue("May-2017"))` only matches at the first of May 2017. While the values are displayed without days, days are probably saved and of influence on the find function. If you manually search (using find or filter), how many values are actually the first of May?

Comment: `Find(DateValue("May-2017"))` *"only matches at the first of May 2017"* That's true. So what is your goal, is it to find the *first date* that occurs during May-2017 in row 1?

Comment: There is a row with 12 cells, one for each month of the year like "May-17". In my calculations I will have a date, which I want to find what cell it belongs to with the month.

Comment: @Voodoo will the last edit work for you? Its strength is that it is independent of any formatting and locale settings.\

Comment: Hey @A.S.H what bibliography did you use for this answer? I'm writing my thesis and should add in some bibliography.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Voodoo that was a week ago, I forgot. Will try to retrieve it to you when my sciencedirect account is reactivated ;)